# Need help creating a window that will enter into a options menu with sliders. In python using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I have created a window with a button saying Enter, when clicked I would like it to proceed to  an options menu with 3 separate sliders whereby the user can adjust them to get a value then press enter. With this value I would like to have a timed output that is the same as that value in seconds. I am very new to Python and need as much help as possible please :)
This is my code so far; and so far the first enter screen will appear then when the enter button is pressed it will load the next window I have created with the three sliders inside it I am not sure this is the best way to do it? Complete novis! 
Please Advise :)

FIRST WINDOW FOR "PRESS ENTER SCREEN"

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
from Tkinter import *
def callback():
    execfile('process screen 2nd draft.py')
    exit
window = Tk()
window.title( 'company name ' )
window.configure ( bg = 'purple' )
label = Label( window, text = 'company name with slogan ' )
label.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn_nxt = Button( window , bg = 'purple',  text = 'Enter' , command=callback , )  
btn_nxt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=100, pady=100)
window.mainloop()
```

SECOND WINDOW FOR OPTIONS MENU 3 SEPERATE SLIDERS

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title( 'random title' )
window.configure( bg = 'purple' )
def show_values () :
    print (w1.get(), w2.get(), w3.get()) 

btn_ent = Button( window , text = 'Enter' , command=show_values) 
btn_ent.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
label_chem= Label( window , bg = 'purple', text = 'Please Choose Chemical Levels' )
label_chem.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
label_nic= Label( window , bg = 'purple', text = 'Nictonine (mg)' )
label_nic.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
label_glyc= Label( window , bg = 'purple', text = 'Glycol (mg)' )
label_glyc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
label_gli= Label( window , bg = 'purple', text = 'Glycerine (mg) ' )
label_gli.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
w1 = Scale( window, bg = 'purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5 )
w1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
w2 = Scale( window, bg = 'purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5 )
w2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
w3 = Scale( window, bg = 'purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5 )
w3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As for me using `execfile()` is wierd solution. You could add widgets into `Frame` and show/hide it with `grid()/grid_forget()` or `pack()/pack_forget()` - everything in one window in one file.

Comment: BTW: if one window has to create second window (and keep first window) then use `Toplevel()` in place of `Tk()` for second window.

Answer (score 0):

First version with `Toplevel` to create second window and timed window - all in one file.

I use `after(time_miliseconds, function_name)` to run function after `time_miliseconds`

Press buton `Enter` to see `timed window`. It closes after constant time.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 

from Tkinter import *

#-----------------------------------------------    
# global variable

time = 0

#-----------------------------------------------    
# second window

def second_window():

    subwindow = Toplevel(window)
    subwindow.title('random title')
    subwindow.configure(bg='purple')

    def show_values():
        print w1.get(), w2.get(), w3.get()

    btn_ent = Button(subwindow, text='Enter', command=timed_window) 
    btn_ent.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_chem = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text='Please Choose Chemical Levels')
    label_chem.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_nic = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text='Nictonine (mg)')
    label_nic.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_glyc = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text='Glycol (mg)')
    label_glyc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_gli = Label(subwindow , bg='purple', text='Glycerine (mg)')
    label_gli.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    w1 = Scale(subwindow, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    w2 = Scale(subwindow, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    w3 = Scale(subwindow, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

#-----------------------------------------------    
# timed window

def timed_window():
    global time

    time = 50

    def countdown():
        global time

        if time > 0:
            time -= 1
            lab.config(text=str(time))
            subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds
        else:
            subwindow.destroy()

    subwindow = Toplevel(window)
    subwindow.title('countdown')
    subwindow.configure(bg='purple')

    lab = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text=str(time))
    lab.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds

#-----------------------------------------------    
# mainwindow

window = Tk()
window.title('company name')
window.configure(bg='purple')
label = Label(window, text='company name with slogan')
label.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn_nxt = Button(window, bg='purple',  text='Enter', command=second_window)  
btn_nxt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=100, pady=100)

window.mainloop()
```

Second version with one window and two frames - all in one file.

I use `pack()` and `pack_forget()` to show and hide frames.
I use the same `timed window` as before.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 

from Tkinter import *

#-----------------------------------------------    

frame_1 = None
frame_2 = None
time = 0

#-----------------------------------------------    

def create_frame_1():
    global frame_1

    frame_1 = Frame(window)
    frame_1.configure(bg='purple')

    label = Label(frame_1, text='company name with slogan')
    label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    btn_nxt = Button(frame_1, bg='purple',  text='Enter', command=show_frame_2)  
    btn_nxt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=100, pady=100)

def create_frame_2():

    def show_values():
        print w1.get(), w2.get(), w3.get()

    global frame_2

    frame_2 = Frame(window)
    frame_2.configure(bg='purple')

    btn_ent = Button(frame_2, text='Enter', command=timed_window) 
    btn_ent.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_chem = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Please Choose Chemical Levels')
    label_chem.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_nic = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Nictonine (mg)')
    label_nic.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_glyc = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Glycol (mg)')
    label_glyc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_gli = Label(frame_2 , bg='purple', text='Glycerine (mg)')
    label_gli.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    w1 = Scale(frame_2, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    w2 = Scale(frame_2, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    w3 = Scale(frame_2, bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

    btn_back = Button(frame_2, text='Back', command=show_frame_1) 
    btn_back.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#-----------------------------------------------    

def show_frame_1():
    frame_2.pack_forget()
    window.title('company name')
    frame_1.pack()

def show_frame_2():
    frame_1.pack_forget()
    window.title('random title')
    frame_2.pack()

#-----------------------------------------------    

def timed_window():
    global time

    time = 50

    def countdown():
        global time

        if time > 0:
            time -= 1
            lab.config(text=str(time))
            subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds
        else:
            subwindow.destroy()

    subwindow = Toplevel(window)
    subwindow.title('countdown')
    subwindow.configure(bg='purple')

    lab = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text=str(time))
    lab.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds

#-----------------------------------------------    

window = Tk()

create_frame_1()
create_frame_2()

show_frame_1()

window.mainloop()
```